# How to measure http timing in .NET Core?

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, system.net.httpwebrequest

CURL is the powerful tool to run the http test on the API endpoint and it provides details timing measurement like lookup, connect, appconnect, pretransfer,starttransfer

How do we capture the similar measurement in .NET Core Web API? we use the system.Net.HttpClient to make a call between two service. Is there any way to capture the details of the response time?

Comment: Refer this URL for more details of http timing measurement https://medium.com/@pvouzis/curl-basic-tutorial-for-http-timing-measurement-dd8dafaa9400

Comment: As far as I recall there is no telemetry inbuilt into the HttpClient. So, you will probably need to use the `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class. Microsoft provides a lot of examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-5.0

Comment: Stopwatch helps to capture end to end response time but I am looking for a  way to capture the breakdown like how much time it spends on  creating a thread pool, connecting the destination app, dns lookup etc

Comment: Do you want to measure the communication time between two services when they create a thread pool?